# Can't access properties of a class

Tags: unity, c#

Sorry for the bad title, but I couldn't think of a way to word my problem for a title.

So I have this script, with two classes:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameItem {

    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    public string ItemDesc { get; set; }

    public Item_Type ItemType { get; set; }

    public int ItemValue { get; set; }

    public int ItemID { get; set; }

    public GameItem() {

    }

    public GameItem(string name, string desc, Item_Type type, int value, int id) {
        this.ItemName = name;
        this.ItemDesc = desc;
        this.ItemType = type;
        this.ItemValue = value;
        this.ItemID = id;
    }
}

public class Weapon : GameItem {

    public string WeapEnch { get; set; }

    public float WeapEffic { get; set; }

    public Weapon() {

    }

    public Weapon(string name, string desc, string ench, float effic, int id) {
        this.ItemType = Item_Type.WEAPON;
        this.ItemName = name;
        this.ItemDesc = desc;
        this.WeapEnch = ench;
        this.WeapEffic = effic;
        this.ItemID = id;
    }

    public void Attack() {

    }
}

public enum Item_Type {
    APPAREL,
    WEAPON,
    TOOL,
    CONSUMABLE,
    BOOK,
    MISC
}
```

And then I have a script for adding items to a list using the constructors:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class InventoryManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<GameItem> GameItems { get; set; }

    void Start () {
        GameItems.Add(new Weapon("Sword", "It's just a sword.", null, 5, 0));
    }

    void Update () {
        if(Input.GetButtonDown("Interact")) {
            Debug.Log(GameItems[0].ItemName);
        }
    }
}
```

So when I create a new Weapon in the list, I can access everything from the `GameItem` class, but nothing from the `Weapon` class, even though I used the Weapon constructor. So I can't use the `Attack ()` function, or access the Weapon's variables. How can I get around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that with your list you dont know if the element is a weapon or a apple. It's just a GameItem. To be able to use the weapon specific properties you need to retrieve the element and cast it back to a Weapon. For example the update in inventory manager will look like this.

```
 void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("a"))
        {
            Debug.Log(GameItems[0].ItemName);
            Weapon currentWeapon =(Weapon)GameItems[0];
            Debug.Log(currentWeapon.ItemName);
            currentWeapon.Attack();
        }
    }
```

What you can do is add a virtual method  `UseItem()` to your GameItem class if you dont want it to be abstract(I would say that it should be). Example :

```
 public virtual void UseItem()
    {

    }
```

Then your weapons class you can do this :

```
  public override void UseItem()
    {
        Attack();
    }
```

Now if you call UseItem on a elemet from your GameItems list and it was added as a weapon it go and call the Attack method from the Weapons class.

An alternative design is to use interfaces to specify different logical boundaries. For example

```
interface IItem
{

}
interface IWeapon : IItem
{

}
interface IFood : IItem
{

} 
interface IRangedWeapon: IWeapon
{

}
void ProcessItems()
{
    foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        if (item is IWeapon) //do some logic
         if (item is IFood) //do some logic
                if (item is IRangedWeapon) //do some logic
    }
}
```

Note this is more or less a pseudo implementation. I also suggest you read up on Polymorphism. For a bit more in depth look and information check out this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68654/abstract-classes-and-interfaces-in-a-game-inventory-system)

Comment: Damn, you beat me with that edit.

Comment: Which one I made like 3 of them :P

Comment: No you didn't (it shows only one for me), but with the addition of the virtual method. I had just written my answer on that approach, as your was missing that when I started typing.

Comment: Ah yes It popped into my head after I added the interface solution and I jumped back to my PC to write it as quickly as I could saying to myself that someone will beat me to it :D